# Lightswitch HTML Client - Disabling/Hiding a button based on permissions

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

This is my scenario. I have a switch (Yes/No) that approves something and I only the user(s) with the permission to be able to ammend this value, so if the user doesnt have access i want it to simply be hidden or disabled, and vice versa...

Under the Access Control tab i have added a permission called ApprovedSwitch (this name for testing purposes), where do i write the code and roughly how do i disable this switch, not the whole screen. im using Visual Studio Lightswitch HTML Client (2013) Update 2, and the C#/JS interface

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Check this out (from Beth Massi's blog):

LightSwitch Tip: A Simple Way to Check User Permissions from the HTML Client
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2013/04/12/lightswitch-tip-a-way-to-check-user-permissions-from-the-html-client.aspx

Comment: link only answers are usually frowned up on within the SO community.  When a link dies or changes it can make old answers especially hard to decipher.  It would be greatly beneficial to copy the meat of the article into your answer.

Comment: sure you are right, but the answer is too big to fit in here

Comment: Not to summarize and call out to what the images and text are providing.

Comment: cheers for the help, unfortunately ive tried this already with little success. it was a while ago though and my knowledge of Lightswitch as expanded in the past couple of months so ill give it another go :)